# ASP.NET - ImageButton within a Repeater refuses to raise a click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, imagebutton

No matter what combination I try, the button (ibtnDeleteDiaryEntry) simply will not raise an event although it does seem to do postback as it should. ViewState is turned on by default, read elsewhere that it is sometimes problematic. Also, I've used the Repeater's OnItemCommand property as required. Any kind of help is appreciated.

EDIT: It seems that the problem is somehow connected to the jQuery UI's Accordion Widget. The repeater is located within a div that is used to initialize the accordion. If I remove the div tags surrounding the repeater, the OnItemCommand event gets called. Very weird.

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repAccordion" OnItemCommand="repAccordion_OnItemCommand" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h3> <%# "Date: " + Eval("date", "{0:d}") %>
            <span class="deleteButtonContainer">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnDeleteDiaryEntry" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("diary_entry_id") %>' CommandName="Delete" AlternateText="ibtnDeleteDiaryEntry" ImageUrl="images/remove_item.png" runat="server" />
            </span>
            </h3>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" ForeColor="#AA0114" Text="Text:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("text") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _db = new PersonalOrganizerDBEntities();
        _diary_entryService = new Diary_EntryService();
        _userService = new UserService();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadItems();
        }
    }

public void LoadItems()
    {
        long currentUserId = (long) Session["userId"];
        User currentUser = _userService.GetById(currentUserId);

        Diary_Entry[] diaryEntriesArray =
            _diary_entryService.GetAll().Where(current => current.diary_id == currentUser.user_id).ToArray();

        if (diaryEntriesArray.Length == 0)
        {
            noItems.Text = "You currently have no diary entries.";
            noItems.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            noItems.Visible = false;
        }

        repAccordion.DataSource = diaryEntriesArray;
        repAccordion.DataBind();
    }

protected void repAccordion_OnItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("test");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work I would recommend removing OnItemCommand from repeater and adding OnClick event for ImageButton instead. In OnClick event in code behind you can cast 'sender' to ImageButton and read CommandArgument value to get diary_entry_id.

Comment: It doesn't fire because of the accordion's header click event. I'm pretty sure it is that because once I move the button elsewhere inside the accordion, all is well.